# Как ускорить мышь в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, мышь, ubuntu-unity

Хочу ускорить мышь. На видео у автора несколько настроек мыши https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb1vODcNoM8. А у меня их почему то только две. Возможно нужно включить режим "Эксперта", чтобы они появились. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ускорение указателя можно посмотреть/изменить, например, с помощью программы `xset`.

посмотреть текущие значения «ускорения» (*acceleration*) и «порога» (*threshold*):

```
$ xset q | grep -A 1 -i pointer
```

пример вывода, где «ускорение» равно `2` (значение дроби `2/1`), а «порог» — `4`:

```
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
```

изменить можно командой:

```
$ xset m [ускорение [порог]]
```

- `ускорение` можно задать целым числом, а можно «простой» дробью вида `1/2`, `10/3` и т.п.
- `порог` — это целое число

приведённые выше значения можно установить командой:

```
$ xset m 2/1 4
```

или (что то же самое):

```
$ xset m 2 4
```

---

если указан только один из этих двух параметров, то он рассматривается как `ускорение`, если опущены оба, восстанавливаются значения по умолчанию.

смысл «порога» объясняется в документации (`man xset`) так:

> By default the pointer (the on-screen representation of the pointing device) will go  `acceleration` times as fast when the device travels more than `threshold` mickeys (i.e. would-be pixels) in 10 ms, including a small transition range. This way, the pointing device can be used for precise alignment when it is moved slowly, yet it can be set to travel across the screen in a flick of the wrist when desired.

мой вольный гугло-перевод:

> по умолчанию указатель (экранное представление указательного устройства, например, «мыши») будет перемещаться в `ускорение` раз быстрее, когда устройство перемещается более чем на `порог` пикселей (*mickeys*) за 10 мс, включая небольшой переходный диапазон. таким образом, указательное устройство может быть использовано для точного позиционирования, когда оно перемещается медленно, но может и быстро переместиться по всему экрану взмахом руки, когда это необходимо.