# Поведение мыши в linux

Tags: linux, мышь

Как в linux сделать нормальное поведение мыши,
уже надоело искать по форумам и сайтам различного рода
решения которые не дают нужного результата.
Дистрибутивов я я уже перепробовал целую кучу, со всеми известными DE
Проблема в том что на мелких деталях мышь бегает быстро, а на дальних дистанция медленно, или не так быстро как хотелось бы.
В Debian lxde вообще настройки мыши в GUI-шном окне не работают но это отдельная тема.
Все что может предложить linux это увеличение или уменьшение акселератора.
Но это не спасает. Если акселератор повысить то мышь вообще становится "бешеная",
если же уменьшить то еле ползает по экрану но на мелких деталях все ровно быстрая. Если убрать на самый минимум, то по мелким деталям уже можно как то попадать и даже комфортно. Но по экрану она тогда вообще чуть перемещается.
Как это все безобразие исправить? В Виндовс все хорошо на мелких деталях она медленная на дальних дистанция быстрая.
Как добиться такого же результата в linux?

P.S. Пробовал xinput --list-props , выбирал свою мышку и
xinput --set-prop "Logitech USB mouse" "libinput Accel Speed" "-0.3" Немного спасает но проблема остается
Потом пробовал xinput --set-prop "Logitech USB mouse" "Coordinate Transform Matrix" по дефолту стоит 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
я ставил 0.3 0 0 0 0.3 0 0 0 1 на мелких деталях все становится как надо, но на дальних дистанция медленная.
И в играх например в maintest тупо смотрит вверх и крутится, кароче "Coordinate Transform Matrix" со значениями отличными от стандартных тоже отпадают.
Остается только уменьшение акселерации, но я как я писал выше, при этом мышь ведет себя тоже неадекватно.
Я бы уже давно пересел на linux но мешает только это безобразие с мышкой остальное всё устраивает.
И да, пробовал множество дистрибутивов, и множество мышек, все одно и тоже.

P.S.S. Если не туда пишу извините, больше не на каких форумах по тематике операционных систем или программирования не зарегистрирован, если можете направьте туда, куда следует задавать этот вопрос.

Comment: логично, что на всех дистрибутивах ведет одинаково - под низом то xorg и ядро в большинстве случаев одно и тоже. Я много лет живу на две системы и каких то особых неудобств не видел. Хотя у меня мышка настроена на "очень бешеную" - 3-4 см - весь экран. Попробуйте ещё на маках. ради эксперимента.

Comment: Может, [это](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration) сколько-нибудь поможет? В особенности со слов "You may need to resort to using more than one method".

Comment: попробуйте разное [ускорение и порог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625773/178576). менять значения лучше понемногу.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev в xinput пробовал, но параметра "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" у меня нет, не знаю почему

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin попробовал xset m 0 0 стала медленнее но все ровно что бы нажать на крестик "закрыть окно" или свернуть надо ловить мышь. Минусовые значения не принимает. Проблема осталась

Comment: минусовые значения чего? вы ускорение хотите уменьшить? так вам дробь надо уменьшать: 1/2, 2/5, 1/3 и т.д. и т.п. // а порог, как я понял из вашего вопроса, вам наоборот надо увеличивать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin просто xset m 2/5 и все? и пробовать подставлять свои значения? Просто я сейчас на Debian lxde тут вообще xset m не работает ни при каких цифрах, тестировал xset на MXLinux